# discordjs trying to make an avatar command but it wont embed an image

Tags: discord.js

```
    client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'avatar')) {
        const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
        const avatarEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(0x333333)
            .setAuthor(user.username)
            .setImage(user.displayAvatarURL);
        message.channel.send(avatarEmbed);
    }

})
```

When doing the command it shows the embed with the username but no image is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in v12 (which you are using if you use `MessageEmbed`) `displayAvatarURL` is a function

```js
.setImage(user.displayAvatarURL);
```

=>

```js
.setImage(user.displayAvatarURL());
```